# Android webservice ERROR “Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1”

Tags: android, web-services, wsdl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 Solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683955/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-solution)

I have looked for solutions for this but i still get this same error when I clean the project or delete and import it back or restarting the eclipse. Even i have tried ["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar/3389640#3389640) this.

Here is what i did at the first place. I have created and android project and tried to put my webservice in it. (wsdl) I have generated the java classes from the wsdl and it gave me some ridiculous errors. I have fixed those errors by simply adding JDK library to the project because I wasnt there.(there were some jars and android(x.y)) Now Im having "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" error and cant fix it.

Any help would be nice. thanks in advance

Comment: -1 duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6683955/808940).  Please do not post duplicate questions ... read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Right-click your project, and go to Properties-->Build Path. Make sure that you have the JARs necessary for the API target specified in your manifest. Delete anything extraneous.

Next, in the main Eclipse menu, click on Project-->Clean, and select your project from the list.

Let me know how that goes--should help.

Comment: nice copy/paste ha ha ha..............