# Android - Phonegap - Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Tags: android, dalvik

I installed this:

https://github.com/mwbrooks/cordova-plugin-menu

and have `cordova 1.8.1` installed.

I copied `"libs/phonegap-1.0.0.jar"` to `ANDROID_PROJECT/libs.`

When i try and run the app in the simulator, i get :

```
"Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1"
```

I believe this is to do with conflicts with libraries, but I don't know what to do to remove the error?

please help.

Comment: looks like a duple of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683955/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-solution or stackoverflow.com/questions/5950054/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1

Answer (score 9):

I have found myself in the same situation after upgrading from 2.0.0 to 2.1.0

First of all make sure you have reconfigured the build path by removing the JAR from the old PhoneGap version and adding the new one.

At this point I started getting the Dalvik error. Cleaning the build environment didn't help.

So I remove the old jar from the libs directory and voilá, it worked.

Comment: Same exact situation here, I was banging my head for 10mins trying to work this one out. Life saver!

Comment: Same thing with my upgrade from 2.1 >> 2.2

Answer (score 4):

Project -> Turn off Build Automatically. Then Build project manually and clean. Then export signed project. Problem has been gone.