# error when using proguard and licensing

Tags: android, proguard, android-lvl

I get a failure when exporting to a signed application with an app that is obfuscated with proguard, and includes market licensing.

It fails with Dalvik error 1.

If I disable proguard it works.
If I disable licensing it works.

I need to use licensing and I need to obfuscate the main code.

Any suggestion?

Thanks
Chris

I found a post with the answer!
Modifying the proguard.bat file worked!
[Android SDK  tools revision 12 has problem with Proguard => error conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605971/android-sdk-tools-revision-12-has-problem-with-proguard-error-conversion-to-d)

Comment: Just a shot in the dark but when I first used progaurd I got errors (can't remember what though). I eventually worked out that it was because there were spaces in the path to my workspace (PC running XP). I ended up relocating my entire workspace to a new folder with no spaces init and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem initially. This is new, turned up when I added the licensing code.

Comment: I tried exporting the license sample app with proguard set. And that failed with the same error.

Comment: Try what is recommended in the accepted answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar

Comment: Have done! Rebuilt a completely new and clean environment. This only happens when trying to export the signed app

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your Proguard config:

```
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
```

Answer (score 0):

I just was fighting with this problem myself
I had my work space on a path with no spaces, I had the sdk and eclpse also on paths with no spaces, none of my projects hand spaces in their names.
I had also updated my sdk, eclipse, and jdk to no avail.
I even found with the new version you gotta remove the  _src folders and did that.
still had the same error; could only export with out proguard

what I ended up doing is editing the proguard.bat file and the problem vanished, found this fix in a discussion about r12 and since nothing else was working I tried it and it worked

it's in: \tools\proguard\bin\proguard.bat

Change

call %java_exe% -jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %*

to

call %java_exe% -jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9