# Android, Proguard 'Unknown option 'and' in argument number 9'

Tags: android, proguard

I'm getting the following error every time I try to export my application from Eclipse.

```
    Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
    proguard.ParseException: Unknown option 'and' in argument number 9
    at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:170)
    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:491)
```

I'm using the defualt proguard.cfg file that Eclipse generated. My android sdk is in C:\Android\SDK(here)

My default.properties file is like this:

```
target=android-7
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

I have also done a clean and build.
I also made sure Eclipse and my SDK tools were up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'spaces in the pathnames' problem is well documented here - note that you can use Junctions/Links to get around this without moving or renaming files...

The Dalvik error is usually just Eclipse 'having a moment' - a 'Clean Project' and Rebuild usually cures it.

Comment: I did the clean and rebuild, but that didn't fix it. And I'm aware that I could get around the renaming, but I just didn't really care that much. Thank you for the input, though.

Comment: What an embarrassing bug. I had space in my path name, but I just had to spend 30 min trying to figure out what the hell is wrong with an error that doesn't say much.

Answer (score 1):

So, in my workspace for the name of the project I had `C:\workspace\Name Android Name` for the name, so I changed that to `C:\workspace\NameName`, then I changed my sdk to `C:\sdk`, then I exported to `C:\NameAndroidName.apk`, and I got the failure to convert to dalvik format error.

And then I went [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605971/android-sdk-tools-revision-12-has-problem-with-proguard-error-conversion-to-d) and that solved the dalvik format error, and it exported successfully.