# Android export error

Tags: android, dalvik

When I try to export my android application, I get this error message..

```
   [2012-05-02 14:34:07 - MyApplication] Dx 
    trouble processing "java/nio/CharBuffer.class":
```

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.

However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.

If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.

If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.

If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.

```
[2012-05-02 14:34:07 - MyApplication] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2012-05-02 14:34:07 - MyApplication] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
[2012-05-02 14:42:22 - MyApplication] Dx 
trouble processing "java/nio/CharBuffer.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.
```

Comment: @cjk As I wrote in the beginning of the question. "When I try to export my android application, I get this error message.."

Comment: By the, I realized that i get this error message when I try to use proguard. There is no error when I remove "proguard.config=proguard.cfg" line from project.properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution..

[Android SDK  tools revision 12 has problem with Proguard => error conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605971/android-sdk-tools-revision-12-has-problem-with-proguard-error-conversion-to)

I downloaded the last version of proguard and it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Are the external references properly included. When you work with external api there often rises exporting problem, although apparently there is no error. Check on with the references.